# How to get node-webkit gui object from an html file rendered by express

Tags: node.js, express, node-webkit

I have a node web app that use express an other node modules
I want to use this web application as a desktop app, so a friend of mine suggested using node webkit.

and yes node webkit makes it look like a desktop app, I can customize every thing I want the toolbar, the window, the scroll bar ...

but the problem I encounter here is the fact that every time I want to start this app, I do need to run the web server and redirect the client to the home page where I have no access to node webkit gui object.

**So here is the structure of the project**

```
Project/
    client/
        index.html => the home page loaded from htt://localhost:9000
    server/
        app.js
    package.json
    index.html => the main page loaded by nodewebkit
```

**the manifest file Project/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodewebkit"
  },
  ...
}
```

**the main file Project/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="server/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Project/app.js**

```
'use strict';

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var config = require(path.resolve('server', 'config/environment'));


//check if server is already running
http.get(config.port, config.ip, function(res) {
    console.log('server is running, redirecting to localhost');
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('localhost') < 0) { 
        window.location = 'http://localhost:' + config.port;
    }
}).on('error', function(e) {

    // Connect to database
    mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

    // Populate DB with sample data
    if(config.seedDB) { require(path.resolve('server', 'config/seed')); }

    // Setup server
    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);

    require(path.resolve('server', 'config/express'))(app);

    //ctrl
    require(path.resolve('server', 'routes'))(app);

    // Start server
    server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
      console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
      if (window.location.href.indexOf('localhost') < 0) { 
        window.location = 'http://localhost:' + config.port;
        }
    });
});
```

**Project/client/index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>app</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="window-toolbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#' title='Minimize' id='windowControlMinimize'></a></li>
                <li><a href='#' title='Maximize' id='windowControlMaximize'></a></li>
                <li><a href='#' title='Close'    id='windowControlClose'   ></a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <section class="container">
          <!-- content -->
        </section>

        <script>
          var nw = require('nw.gui');
          var win = nw.Window.get();
          win.isMaximized = false;

          // Min
          document.getElementById('windowControlMinimize').onclick = function()
          {
              win.minimize();
          };

          // Close
          document.getElementById('windowControlClose').onclick = function()
          {
              win.close();
          };

          // Max
          document.getElementById('windowControlMaximize').onclick = function()
          {
              if (win.isMaximized)
                  win.unmaximize();
              else
                  win.maximize();
          };

          win.on('maximize', function(){
              win.isMaximized = true;
          });

          win.on('unmaximize', function(){
              win.isMaximized = false;
          });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no problem when I try to load the node webkit gui object from Project/index.html
but when I try to access it from Project/client/index.html using http I always get errors;

if anyone has a solution, workaround or can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using express server, the javascript on the main index.html and javascript loaded by express won't run under the same context(think of of like, what if someone access the script from another web browser?).

so if you are using express as only for routing purpose you may consider using single page app frameworks like [angularjs](https://angularjs.org) which has routing and works very well with node-webkit